# rewrite htaccess from xyz.com/?type=test&s=test2 to xyz.com/test/test2

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

what i need is for a search thing, so the test2 is changeable and need the link to change too.
how can i do this in `.htaccess`?

this is what i thought to do.

`RewriteRule ^xyz.com/test/(.*)$  ^xyz.com/?type=test&s=$1 [NC,L]`

any idea?
Thanks!

my Wordpress `.htacess`:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]


RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(.*)$ index.php?type=test&s=$1 [NC,L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0):

You will be looking at something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(.*)$ ?type=$1&s=$2 [NC,L]
```

Not sure it will work without the filename, though. If that's the case point the rewrite to your file that handles requests, e.g.:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(.*)$ index.php?type=$1&s=$2 [NC,L]
```

You don't include the domain name in the RewriteRule match pattern.

Comment: Thanks Michal for the answer, still not working :( i'm using this for wordpress search form, updated the question with the full .htaccess

Comment: The rule doesn't work because the previous one kicks in earlier as it matches all requests. This is actually tricky in this case. I don't have much experience with WordPress so I'm not sure how to go around this problem. If I figure something out I'll update my answer.

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_Advanced_Topics#How_do_you_get_cruft_free_URIs_for_search_results.3F), @Jimmy. Should help a bit at least. What's your `type` param?